# What does com mean on a circut diagram?

Tags: circuit-analysis

What does com mean on a circuit diagram ([source](http://www.instructables.com/id/Stepper-Motor-Generator/))?
[image]

What are com 1 and com 2 representing?

Answer (score 1):

They represent the common connection for phases 1 and 2 of the unipolar stepper motor respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Common - its a centre tap on the stepper motor winding - you get half voltage - out of phase - on either half of the coil.

In this circuit which is using the stepper motor as a generator its not used.